# MVC 3 Adding a local Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently going through the MvcMusicSore tutorial (MVC 3). I have full sql server 2008 installed and created a local database by running the SqL scripts included in the MvcMusicStore-Assets data folder. However when trying to add the mdf to the AppFolder in Visual Studio 2010 I get the error Access Denied. I am completely stuck at this point and would appreciate any help to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the App_Data folder?  Alternatively, you could leave it in the default SQL server folder and configure your web.config's connection string.

Comment: does it work if you 'run as administrator'?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the mdf file is locked by some other process, not allowing the application to read it. If you mounted the database on SQL Server you need to use a connection string with the machine name instead of specifying the mdf file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy or modify a live working database. And I don't see why you should.
You need connecting to it? Pick a way. LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate, ADO.NET...

If you really want to copy the database file for some reason, you must first stop the MSSQL Service (or detach the database), then do that.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you shouldn't need to add the actual .mdf into your project.  If you have it running on your local SQL Server instance, you should be able to add it via Visual Studio's Server Explorer (plus that gets you your connection string).